# Div horizontally align centered with stacking

Tags: html, css, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 and what I am trying to achieve is as follows:

I have a big div of width 100%

```
.bigdiv { width: 100% }
```

In that bigdiv, I want to put 4 small divs. of same width, but one of them is of different height.

I want those 4 divs must be centered align (horizontally) in .bigdiv div. However if I resize the window, then they should flow down and get stacked upon each other, but still aligned in centre. To fluidly stack on window resize, I tried `float:left` but that does nto give the desired view.

I am having hard time to keep these small divs in the centre, before and after resize. Please see the attached image illustrating possible scenarios 
[image]
[image][image][image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your current attempt please? preferably in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), also are you using bootstrap classes at all in this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using `display: inline-block` in the children and `text-align:center` in the parent:

**HTML**

```
<div class="bigdiv">
    <div class="smalldiv"></div>
    <div class="smalldiv"></div>
    <div class="smalldiv"></div>
    <div class="smalldiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bigdiv {
    text-align:center;
}

.smalldiv{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.smalldiv:nth-child(3){
    height: 200px;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/9zAQM/1)**

Comment: Thanks koala_dev . Never imagined it can be done so easily. Your solution is very neat.

Comment: koala_dev I put some content in the box and made text align left in small boxes as http://jsfiddle.net/5RVT6/1/ then all small divs get moved on top while it was earlier staying at the bottom. How to get them stay at the bottom.

Comment: @JVK add `vertical-align:bottom` to the small boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/5RVT6/2/

Answer (score 1):

Check the bootstrap documentation about grid... to center the divs inside your bigdiv, you must add a div with class: .container and inside this, a div with class row, then your cols... like this:

```
<div class="bigdiv">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">Col 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Col 2</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Col 3</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Col 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Remember, bootstrap uses a 12 columns grid, so replace the number in col-lg-3 by your needs.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gaSJR/